# Callback execution timing not as expected in Chrome

Tags: javascript, web-applications, frontend

[This blog post](https://itnext.io/how-javascript-works-in-browser-and-node-ab7d0d09ac2f) explains how JavaScript execution works under the hood. It describes the stack, event loop, callback queue and web api context.

I tried the following example:

```
function main() {
  setTimeout( () => alert('World') , 1000 ); // don't dismiss this alert for about 5 seconds
  setTimeout( () => alert('Mars') , 5000 );
}

main();
```

I expect both timers to run in parallel. Once I dismiss the first alert, the next alert comes immediately. This is the behaviour in Firefox and Edge. But in Chrome, the second alert comes 5 seconds after the first one is dismissed. Not expected.

Is this a problem with Chrome implementation? Is Chrome trying to do some optimization?

Versions: Firefox Quantum 61.0.1, Chrome 69.0.3497.100, Edge 42.17134.1.0

Answer (score 1):

One of the idiosyncrasies about JS is that execution environments differ, which you seem privy to the different engines available.

In Chrome, `alert` is a blocking method which will halt execution.

Consider this example:

```
(() => {
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    setTimeout(() => console.log(i), i*1000)
  }
  setTimeout(() => alert('World'), 1000)
  setTimeout(() => alert('Mars'), 5000)
})()
```

You will see that the counter stops and resumes after the alert has been dismissed. However, you're expectations are correct where JS is generally considered `non-blocking` and in more often than not, methods such as `setTimeout` would be ran asynchronously (such as in the for loop where the timer must be incremented for the desired behavior).

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: don't use `alert` it's bad practice. Use `console.log`

Calls such as `setTimeout()` are DOM API's. They are not run in the main execution stack (LIFO). Instead they are placed in a parallel  thread where they are run; let call this the DOM thread.

In this instance (first setTimeout = t1) t1 is placed on the DOM thread followed by t2 and `main()` continues to execute. When t1 times-out it's callback is placed on the event queue; when t2 times-out it's callback is placed onto the same queue.

Callbacks in the event queue are then plucked off in order and executed in the main thread. However each one can only happen in those snapshots of time when main stack is empty and the browser is not busy. `setTimeout` only guarantees that the callback won't be called BEFORE the specified time.

If you were to user console.log instead of alert you would see the code executing as expected. Using alert is bad practice and actually halts your JS execution in Chrome (from what I can tell).

[setTimeout with and without alert](http://%3Ca%20class=%22jsbin-embed%22%20href=%22https://jsbin.com/qozepuxata/embed?js,console%22%3EJS%20Bin%20on%20jsbin.com%3C/a%3E%3Cscript%20src=%22https://static.jsbin.com/js/embed.min.js?4.1.4%22%3E%3C/script%3E)